# How to solve "property with retain (or strong) attribute must be of object type" on React Native?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, podfile

I am trying to build a React Native app in iOS that use Firebase, but I got this error:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIZLh.png)

`error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type`
`While building module 'FirebaseStorage'`

This is a the error log:

```
In file included from /Users/xxxx/Documents/Grups/grups/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.h:18:
/Users/xxxx/Documents/Grups/grups/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:50:13: fatal error: could not build module 'FirebaseFirestore'
    #import <FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
While building module 'FirebaseStorage' imported from /Users/xxxx/Documents/Grups/grups/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:78:
In file included from <module-includes>:2:
/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grups-ekqodkfcidbeowgmbeplgbgpybif/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage.framework/Headers/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h:315:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
```

This is my podfile:

```
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'grups' do
  
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    #:fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    #:flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'grupsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "grups",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.4",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

How can I solve that?

I didn't find other solutions here.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens with firebase react native 15 in my project, downgrade to react native firebase 14.11.0 works for me.

Comment: but older versions of firebase SDK are also broken eg see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29681